# Laravel Eloquent: how to write this sql statement in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Balance sheet query

[image]

```
SELECT 
      dateN
     ,memo
     ,(COALESCE(CASE WHEN drcr = 'dr' THEN amount END,0)) total_debits
     ,(COALESCE(CASE WHEN drcr = 'cr' THEN amount END,0)) total_credits,
    @b := @b + (COALESCE(CASE WHEN drcr = 'cr' THEN amount END,0)) - (COALESCE(CASE WHEN drcr = 'dr' THEN amount END,0)) balance
FROM
    (SELECT @b := 0.0) AS dummy 
  CROSS JOIN
    tbl_bankrecords
ORDER BY
    dateN
```

Comment: i am trying it says column not found in laravel

Comment: DateN rather than dateN in SELECT and ORDER BY?